# Why is numeric_limits<uint16_t>::max() not equal to -1?

Tags: c++, standards, numeric, unsigned-integer, compile-time-constant

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

static_assert(-1 == numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()); // ok
static_assert(-1 == numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max()); // ok
static_assert(-1 == numeric_limits<uint16_t>::max()); // error

int main()
{
    cout << numeric_limits<uint16_t>::max() << endl;
    cout << uint16_t(-1) << endl;
}
```

output:

```
65535
65535
```

**Why is** `numeric_limits<uint16_t>::max()` **not equal to -1?**

Update:

According to [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits):

> Similarly USHRT_MAX may not be of an unsigned type: its type may be
>   int.

Comment: "may be int" and "is int" are two very different things

Comment: Could you explain in more (well, any) detail why you think it _should_ equal -1? It's hard to clear up a misconception when we don't know what it is!

Comment: To me, -1 means 0xFFFF...., so for an unsigned integer, it should be equal to the maximum value of that integer type.

Comment: Okay. Well, -1 does not mean 0xFFFF. It means -1. It sounds like you're treating C++ as if it were raw-programming bits in memory. It is not.

Comment: (Even if it _did_ work that way, on modern systems it'd be more likely representable as 0xFFFFFFFF. Are you assuming that `int`s are 16-bit like in the 1980s?)

Comment: @xmllmx Note the addendum to my answer, about platform specific/dependent behaviour.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Integer conversions and promotions

The `uint16_t` value goes through *integer promotion* whereas for (your particular platform; see below) the `uint32_t` and `uint64_t` cases the `-1` *value* (not an integer literal, per se, but the unary minus operator applied to the integer literal `1`), goes through *integer conversion* with a resulting value that is equal to the maximum respective value of the `uint32_t` and `uint64_t` types, due to the integer congruence between the source and the destination values of this conversion.

```
static_assert(-1 == std::numeric_limits<std::uint64_t>::max());
//            ^^
//            | Integer conversion:
//            |   Destination type: uint64_t
//            |   Resulting value: std::numeric_limits<std::uint64_t>::max()

static_assert(-1 == std::numeric_limits<std::uint32_t>::max());
//            ^^
//            | Integer conversion:
//            |   Destination type: uint32_t
//            |   Resulting value: std::numeric_limits<std::uint32_t>::max()

static_assert(-1 == std::numeric_limits<std::uint16_t>::max());
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                  | Integer promotion:
//                  |   Destination type: int
//                  |   Resulting value: std::numeric_limits<std::uint16_t>::max()
```

---

From [[expr.eq]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.eq#1) and [[expr.eq]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.eq#6) [**emphasis** mine]:

> #### [expr.eq]/1
>
> The `==` (equal to) and the `!=` (not equal to) operators group
>   left-to-right. The operands shall have arithmetic, enumeration,
>   pointer, or pointer to member type, or type `std​::​nullptr_­t`. The
>   operators `==` and `!=` both yield `true` or `false`, i.e., a result
>   of type `bool`. In each case below, **the operands shall have the same
>   type after the specified conversions have been applied**.
>
> #### [expr.eq]/6
>
> If both operands are of arithmetic** or enumeration type, the usual **arithmetic conversions are performed on both operands**; each of
>   the operators shall yield `true` if the specified relationship is
>   `true` and `false` if it is `false`.

From [[conv.integral]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.integral#1) and [[conv.integral]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.integral#2):

> #### [conv.integral]/1
>
> A prvalue of an integer type can be converted to a prvalue of another integer type. A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type.
>
> #### [conv.integral]/2
>
> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo `2n` where `n` is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [ Note: In a two's complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation).  — end note ]

This alone should yield the same behaviour for all your three examples. However, what differs for the `uint16_t` case is that [[conv.integral]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.integral#5) applies:

> #### [conv.integral]/5
>
> The conversions allowed as integral promotions are excluded from the set of integral conversions.

From [[conv.rank]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.rank#1)

> #### [conv.rank]/1
>
> Every integer type has an integer conversion rank defined as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> (1.3) The rank of `long long int` shall be greater than the rank of `long
>   int`, which shall be greater than **the rank of `int`, which shall be
>   greater than the rank of `short int`**, which shall be greater than the
>   rank of `signed char`.
>
> (1.4) The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the corresponding signed integer type.

the integer conversion rank of `uint16_t` (same rank or lower than `short int`) is lower than that of `int`, which means that [[conv.prom]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.prom#1) applies for `uint16_t` [**emphasis** mine]:

> #### [conv.prom]/1
>
> A prvalue of an integer type other than `bool`, `char16_­t`, `char32_­t`, or `wchar_­t` **whose integer conversion rank is less than the rank of `int` can be converted to a prvalue of type `int`** if `int` can represent all the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a prvalue of type `unsigned int`.

---

## Platform dependent behaviour

*However*, whilst we were able to make an argument for `uint16_t` above due to the *lower bound requirement on the maximum value* of an `unsigned short int`—guaranteeing that `uint16_t` always has a lower integer conversion rank than `int`—we cannot make the converse argument for the fact that `uint32_t` will *never have **lower** integer conversion rank* than `int`, as the ISO C++ Standard places no *upper bounds on the maximum value* requirement on the fundamental integer types.

From [[basic.fundamental]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.fundamental#2) and [[basic.fundamental]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.fundamental#3) [extract, **emphasis** mine]:

> #### [basic.fundamental]/2
>
> There are five standard signed integer types : “`signed char`”,
>   “`short int`”, “`int`”, “`long int`”, and “`long long int`”. In this
>   list, **each type provides at least as much storage as those preceding
>   it in the list**. [...] Plain `int`s **have the natural size suggested
>   by the architecture of the execution environment**; the other signed
>   integer types are provided to meet special needs.
>
> #### [basic.fundamental]/3
>
> For each of the standard signed integer types, there exists a
>   corresponding (but different) standard unsigned integer type:
>   “`unsigned char`”, “`unsigned short int`”, “`unsigned int`”,
>   “`unsigned long int`”, and “`unsigned long long int`”, each of which
>   occupies the same amount of storage and has the same alignment
>   requirements as the corresponding signed integer type; [...]
>
> The signed and unsigned integer types **shall satisfy the constraints
>   given in the C standard, section 5.2.4.2.1**.

And, from the [C11 Standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) [extract, **emphasis** mine]:

> #### 5.2.4.2.1  Sizes of integer types `<limits.h>`
>
> [...] Their implementation-defined values shall be **equal or greater
>   in magnitude** (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.
>
> [...]
>
> - maximum value for an object of type `short int`: `SHRT_MAX +32767`
> - maximum value for an object of type `int`: `INT_MAX +32767`
>
> [...]

Note that these *maximum values* describes the *lower bound on the maximum values* that the respective fundamental integer type shall be able to store, whereas there is no requirement placed on the upper bound of these maximum values. Moreover, recall from the [basic.fundamental]/2 quote above that each subsequent fundamental (signed) integer type needs only provide *at least* as much storage as the one proceeding it (in the list).

This means that, in theory, a platform could implement `short int` and `int` as 32 bit wide and 64 bit wide integers, respectively, meaning that, on this platform, `uint32_t` would have same integer conversion rank as (`unsigned`) `short int`, which would mean a **lower** conversion rank than `int`, in which case `[conv.prom]/1` would apply also for the `uint32_t` example *on this particular platform*.

Answer (score 9):

Because `-1` isn't converted to a `uint16_t`.

`std::numeric_limits<std::uint16_t>::max()` is promoted to an `int`, and `-1 != 65535`.